# Create a dynamic element with Lorem ipsum in jsp page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

Today working on testing views, and after getting tired of writing crap on the keyboard, to check overlay

Is there any way to generate a dynamic text "lorem ipsum" in a jsp.

For example, i write

```
        <div>
            <lorem:ipsum ></lorem:ipsum>
        </div>
```

And get

```
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius lectus urna, vel consequat lacus tristique eu. In tempor, erat a pellentesque laoreet, dolor justo tristique odio, ac viverra libero felis et nisl. Etiam sodales ligula at mi tincidunt commodo. Fusce nec turpis nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec neque magna, euismod a feugiat in, convallis at orci. Nulla et lacinia odio, ullamcorper mollis justo. Phasellus tempor erat eu pellentesque
    </div>
```

would be interesting to have options, as maximum and minimun length

```
        <div>
            <lorem:ipsum max="500" min="50" ></lorem:ipsum>
        </div>
```

And get text in the interval

The idea would be that each execution of jsp different text is generated, to not have to be copying and pasting

Is there something?

Comment: Write your own custome tag <lorem:ipsum> .. In the tag handler use http://loremipsum.sourceforge.net/ .. You dont really need Spring MVC for that ..

Comment: What does 'today evidence to a hearing' have to do with it? What does it even mean?

Comment: @EJP Sorry had worked several hours :(, my squirrel not run, i edit post.

Comment: You can use a website that generate or provide Lorem Ipsum with HTML like these: 
http://www.lorem-ipsum-html.com/
http://www.blindtextgenerator.com/lorem-ipsum